# multiplicative group using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to create a multiplicative group of order q.

This code generates an additive cyclic group of order 5

`from sympy.combinatorics.generators import cyclic
list(cyclic(5))`

`[(4), (0 1 2 3 4), (0 2 4 1 3), (0 3 1 4 2), (0 4 3 2 1)]`

Any help ?

Answer (score -1):

after reading more on the subject ,

> Multiplicative group Z * p
>
> In classical cyclic group gryptography we usually use multiplicative group Z p * , where p is prime.
> Z p *
> = { 1, 2, .... , p - 1} combined with multiplication of integers mod p

So it is simply

`G2=  [ i for i in range(1, n-1 )] #G2 multiplicativ Group of ordern`

Comment: How is this a group? What about the group operations, inverse and multiplication? What if n is not prime?

Comment: this is the case i need, i'm working in a cryptographic context when n is prime

Comment: That still doesn't make it a group, you don't have any operations defined on it.

Comment: yes it is a group, the Zp* multiplicativ group, which is known in cryptography as I just discovered. Zp* uses only the integers between 1 and p - 1 (p is a prime number), and its basic operation is multiplication